# Creating a new IndexPath to be used with two-dimensional array data structure (App Development with Swift, project EmojiDictionary, page # 556)

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner and am trying to tweak the *EmojiDictionary* (page # 556) project from Apple's **App Development with Swift** book by changing the one-dimensional data array to two-dimensional.

Here's the original implementation:

```
Data Class:

class Emoji {
        var symbol: String
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var usage: String

        init(symbol: String, name: String, description: String, usage: String) 
        {
            self.symbol = symbol
            self.name = name
            self.description = description
            self.usage = usage
        }
    }



Original Data Structure: An array of emojis: 
 var emojis: [Emoji] = [...]



@IBAction func unwindToEmojiTableView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
        let sourceViewController = segue.source as! AddEditEmojiTableViewController
        if let emoji = sourceViewController.emoji {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                emojis[selectedIndexPath.row] = emoji

                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {

                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: emojis.count, section: 0)
                emojis.append(emoji)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's what I am trying to do:

```
My Data Structure: Array of arrays:
var emojis: [[Emoji]] = [ [Emoji(...), Emoji(...), ...], [Emoji(...), etc...]  ]


@IBAction func unwindToEmojiTableView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
        let sourceViewController = segue.source as! AddEditEmojiTableViewController
        if let emoji = sourceViewController.emoji {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                emojis[selectedIndexPath.row][selectedIndexPath.row] = emoji

                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {
```

> ```
>                 let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: ?, section: 0)
>                 emojis[?].append(emoji)
> ```

```
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to work. The code (with question marks) in the block quote is where I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: selectedIndexPath.row, section: selectedIndexPath.section)
 emojis[selectedIndexPath.section].append(emoji)
```

If you are trying to append to the object that is selected for a specific section.